# Count number of cells with certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Unfortunately I need to use excel to solve an issue.

I have a (huge) sheet with many columns.
I need to create a summary of some sort.

What I need to know is how to count the number of cells (in a column) with certain criteria.

e.g:

```
              COL1       COL2     COL3
----------------------------------------
ROW1          apple      food       AB
ROW2          apple      food       AB
----------------------------------------
```

In the case above, if the criteria is apple,food,AB it would return 2. (the criteria will mainly be string matching inside the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use the `=COUNTIF`

here are some tutorials with explanations

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/somethingiffunctions/ss/2011-04-16-Excel-2010-Countif-Function-Step-By-Step-Tutorial.htm

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/01/31/use-excel-countifs-to-count-with-multiple-criteria/

Comment: yes COUNTIF can be used, but I need to use more than one criteria.

Comment: You didn't mention which version of Excel you are using. `=COUNTIFS` (note trailing `S`) matches multiple criteria and is available in 2007 & later.

Comment: if you are referring to Andy Holaday's `COUNTIFS` then you shouldn't have accepted this post, you should ask Andy to post a separate response

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 onwards

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A2,"food",B1:B2,"apple",C1:C2,"AB")
```